# Seeing output from string.maketrans

Tags: python

This is in Python 2.7.
string.maketrans function is supposed to return a translation map which is a string of exactly 256 chars.

Why can't I see this string using the print command?

```
allchars = string.maketrans('','')
print 'all chars are = ', allchars
```

The output of this is blank.

I can use this:

```
print repr(allchars)
```

and this will return the table, but I'm wondering why print won't show anything

Answer (score 1):

Note that the majority of the characters in a translation table aren't printable. You can send them to the terminal, but they won't do exactly what you expect.

Here's what I get using Python 2.7.15rc1:

```
>>> out = string.maketrans('', '')
>>> print out



 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

In other words, an ASCII table, followed by a bunch of nonsense (attempting to decode bytes above 127).

Comment: I was going to post the same thing.  I get this same output.

Comment: Not from the prompt, but rather running a Python program.

Comment: From the prompt or using the repr I get: '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`mbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\x etc...

Comment: so this is all fine. I'm wondering about the print statement within a program

Comment: @Kris You get the same output within a program as in the repl.